# Update array at different indexes with the same value in one go

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array `a = [8, 3, true, 9, false]`, and an indices array `b = [1, 3, 4]`. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
a[b] = false;
```

So that a becomes `[8, false, true, false, false]`?

Comment: Not directly, no. You can use a `forEach`: `b.forEach(idx => a[idx] = false);` or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax won't work here, since `b` is an array, JS will try and convert `b` to a primitive by calling `toString()` on that array. Since `b.toString()` results in `"1,3,4"` you'll end up adding `"1,3,4"` as a property in your array:

```js
const a = [8, 3, true, 9, false];
const b = [1, 3, 4];

a[b] = false; // adds property "1,3,4" to the array `a`, sets it to false
console.log(a["1,3,4"]); // false
```

You would need to manually loop through the indexes in `b`, and for each index set that index within `a` to false. This could be done with a regular for loop or [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const a = [8, 3, true, 9, false];
const b = [1, 3, 4];

b.forEach(idx => a[idx] = false);
console.log(a); // [8, false, true, false, false]
```

If you want to keep this immutable and not modify the original array, one idea could be to use `Object.assign()` to merge and overwrite the indexes specified in `b`:

```js
const a = [8, 3, true, 9, false];
const b = [1, 3, 4];

const res = Object.assign([], a, ...b.map(idx => ({[idx]: false})));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support from the language but you can easily write a function for this.

```js
const at = (ii, y) => (x, i) => ii.includes(i) ? y : x;
```

It is a curried function which takes a list of indexes `ii` and a new value `y` for these indexes. Then it returns a function that takes a value `x` and an index `i`. If `i` belongs to `ii` then returns new value `y` otherwise keep value `x`.

This makes it convenient to inline it when mapping an array:

```js
[8, 3, true, 9, false].map(at([1, 3, 4], false));
//  ^        ^  ^
//  1        3  4
//
//=> [8, false, true, false, false]
```

If you want to be able to assign different values at different indexes, then we can use the following data structure:

```
[[xi, xv], [yi, yv], [zi, zv], ...]
```

It represents a list of pairs where the first element represents the index and the second element represents the new value.

To support this we need to rewrite `at`.

For each `(x, i)` it tries to find a pair where the 1st el. is equal to `i`. If there's a result return the pair, otherwise return a temporary pair `[, x]`. Finally access the 2nd element of the pair which will be the value at that index.

```js
const at = (...ys) => (x, i) => (ys.find(([j]) => j === i) || [, x])[1];
```

We can still inline it as above:

```js
[8, 3, true, 9, false].map(at([1, 'x'], [3, 'y'], [4, 'z']));
//  ^        ^  ^
//  1        3  4
//  x        y  z
//
// [8, "x", true, "y", "z"]
```